Consider p, q $\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Let A $\in \mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$. Prove that $||A||_p = ||A^T||_q$
I saw a solution on Stackexchange but that involves Banach-spaces and duality. Can it be done without using that?
I started by considering 2 vectors k $\in \mathbb{R^{n\times 1}}$ and l $\in \mathbb{R^{m\times 1}}$ with $||k||_p = ||l||_q = 1$. Then by Holder's inequality, we have for 2 vectors of the same length that $|x^Ty| \leq ||x||_p||y||_q$ when $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.
I am defining a norm of a matrix in the standard sense given here.
Considering $x = Ak$ and $y = l$, we get:
\begin{equation}{
 |k^TA^Tl| \leq ||Ak||_p||l||_q = ||Ak||_p
}\end{equation}
Now, we also have by considering $x = k$ and $y = A^Tl$ that
\begin{equation}{
 |k^TA^Tl| \leq ||k||_p||A^Tl||_q = ||A^Tl||_q
}\end{equation}
According to sub-multiplicative property of all p-norms, we also have that
\begin{equation}{
 ||A^Tl||_q \leq ||A^T||_q||l||_q = ||A^T||_q
}\end{equation}
And again a similar expression for $||A||_p$.
However, I am unable to proceed further in the sense of achieving another upper bound for the quantity $||Ak||_p$. I think that that would lead to the solution. I also thought of using Lagrange Multipliers for the quantity $|k^TA^Tl| = |l^TAk|$ and then applying sandwich theorem in some way that $||Ak||_p$ has nowhere to go but to reach $||A||_p$ in the supremum constrained sense but was unable to proceed on the same. Any help will be appreciated.
(P.S. This is my 1st question on SE. Please correct me if I have made any mistakes. Thanks!)

The key is to examine the case when Hölder's inequality attains equality.
If $v \ne 0$ satisfies $\|Av\|_p=\|A\|_p\|v\|_p$, then consider $u$ such that $u_i = (Av)_i^{p/q}$. Then $u$ and $Av$ attain equality in Hölder's inequality, that is, $$|u^\top Av| = \|u\|_q \|Av\|_p = \|u\|_q \|A\|_p \|v\|_p.$$
Applying Hölder's inequality the other way yields
$$|u^\top A v| \le \|A^\top u\|_q \|v\|_p \le \|A^\top\|_q \|u\|_q \|v\|_p.$$
Combining these two results yields $\|A\|_p \le \|A^\top\|_q$. A similar argument can be used to show the reverse inequality.

Can you please explain why $u$ and $Av$ should attain equality in Holder's inequality?

@Ojas See the statement and/or proof of Hölder's inequality, e.g. here.
